# Taking screenshots with python pillow resulting in weird regions

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, screenshot

I'm taking a screenshot of my screen using the python pillow module, and editing bbox to take a picture of a certain region. This is returning very weird results, because when I looked up how bbox worked, everything says (left, upper, right, lower), so  assumed that it took a screenshot where the top-left corner is (left, upper) and the bottom-right corner is (right, lower). This does not seem to be the case, because when I take a screenshot of my screen with the dimensions (100, 100, 500, 500), it takes a screenshot of the bottom-left of my screen. The x positions seem to be working, but the y positions are much lower than expected. I'd expect it to take a screenshot of around the top-left of my screen. Here is my code:

```
import time
from PIL import ImageGrab
bbox = (100, 100, 500, 500)
time.sleep(3)
screenshot = ImageGrab.grab(bbox)
screenshot.save("screenshot.png")
screenshot.close()
```

Comment: Are you on **macOS**? It looks like the code is wrong at this line `args += ["-R", f"{left},{right},{right-left},{bottom-top}"]` and it should be `args += ["-R", f"{left},{top},{right-left},{bottom-top}"]` You should be able to work around it by copying the code and running `screencapture` in a `subprocess` yourself.

Comment: Are the 4 coordinates of the bbox not (starting x position, starting y position, ending x position, ending y position)? Yes Im on macOS

Comment: They are, yes. But the code in Pillow is wrong. See the 5th/6th line here and read my previous comment and you'll see what I mean https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/PIL/ImageGrab.html#grab

Comment: Issue to be fixed in next release https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/6308